# Unauthorized error in browser console when exporting to PDF from embedded Tableau report

Tags: javascript, tableau-api

I have a working configuration of Tableau reports embedded in our web site (JavaScript API, Trusted Authentication).
There is a problem with exporting report to PDF. An unauthorized error (401) shows up in browser console when opening export to PDF dialog. It looks like "Sheets to export" section should display view thumbnails, for me it shows only blank squares with view name.

What I see in browser console is:

```
GET https://[host]/t/[site]/thumb/views/[view] 401 (Unauthorized)
```

Actual response for that request is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <error xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <code>46</code>
    <message>Not authorized</message>
    <details>No valid session found. (errorCode=46)</details>
</error>
```

Export itself works ok, and PDF file is created. Any ideas why just the view thumbnail query fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone faces the same problem: I've contacted the Tableau support and it looks like that this behaviour is connected with Trusted Authentication. In short trusted tickets are limited to the content that they were issued for, and worksheet thumbnails are not considered an integral part of a workbook. 
The solution for this would be to enable Unrestricted Tickets in tableau server, but it is not acceptable for us as it allows the user with access to the Tableau report embedded in our web application to access Tableau Server web interface.

Comment: Hi @Wojtek, I am facing a similar issue, but in my case the session expires after a timeout and i see a lot of 400 errors, do you know a way to handle the session timeout using the javascript api and reload the page or display some alert to the user?

Comment: I have not faced session timeouts, the only timeout that comes to my mind is related to ticket being redeemed after its lifetime, I would double check if tickets issued by Tableau Server (step 3 -  https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/trusted_auth.htm) are not written into urls rendered on web page.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.will check it accordingly.